# Почему код выводит "s" , если в `list_1` нет "2"?

Tags: python

Создаю шифр, во время его задания столкнулся с его неработоспособностью, решил проверить, как будет работать этот код:

```
list_1 = ["A"]
b = "2"
for b in list_1:
    n = 0
    if b == list_1[n]:
        print("s")
    n += 1
```

И мне вывелось на экран `s`, а
это означает, что "2" есть в `list_1`? Почему этот код выводит "s" , если в `list_1` нет "2"?

Comment: `["A"]` - это не `dict`, а `list`.

Comment: я знаю , просто его так назвал , сейчас исправлю и в коде и тут

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы пишете

```
for b in list_1:
```

вы забываете о предыдущем значении `b`. Теперь b будет принимать друг за другом значения из `list_1`. При первой итерации (и последней, так как в `list_1` всего 1 элемент) `b` будет равно нулевому элементу списка. Конечно же,

```
if b == list_1[n]:  # b = list_1[0], n = 0
```

вернёт `True`.
 Потому и выводит `s`.